# Not getting breakpoint option for lambda expression in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

When I add a breakpoint on a lambda expression, IDE is not offering me options as mentioned [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/09/02/debugging-lambdas-and-macro-expansion-extractor/). I am using IDEA Community 2018.3 edition.

[image]

Comment: Show the whole line involved?

Comment: In the gutter you can see it's a lambda, do you still need full line? It's internal source code, the lambda is like `Optional.ifPresent { ... }`

Comment: `Optional.ifPresent { ... }` is not a Java code. Are you coding in Groovy or did you use wrong brackets?

Comment: It's not as is - just pseudo code

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Do you face the same problem for other lambdas, e.g. "private static final Predicate<Object> isNull = x -> x == null;"?

Comment: @y.bedrov I'm getting the option for the lambda you mentioned :O

Comment: I have updated the code snippet in question now.